# How many different license plates start with the letter A if letters and digits cannot be repeated? Enter the exact numeric answer.

Tags: combinatorics

a) Consider the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 35$. How many different solutions does this equation have 
if all the variables must be positive integers? Enter the exact numeric answer.

b) Suppose that a license plate consists of three letters followed by three digits. How many different license plates start with the letter A if letters and digits cannot be repeated? Enter the exact numeric answer.

**My work**

a)  $C(38,35)$

b)$1*P(26,2)*P(10,3)$

A_ _ _ _ _ . The last three number should not be repeated, so $P(10,3)$ and then the letters can be chosen randomly so $C(26,2)$

Comment: To chose the letters, you don't want $C(26,2)$, because order matters. Since one letter is already used, you want $P(25,2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Almost.  The restriction is that all variables must be *positive* integers, so we can rewrite this as

$$
y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 31
$$

with $y_i = x_i-1$ being a non-negative integer for all $i$.  Then stars-and-bars gives us $C(34, 31) = C(34, 3)$.

(b) Almost.  As Tony Jacobs points out in the comments, the two letters should be represented by $P(25, 2)$, since you have to avoid $A$ (leaving only $25$ letters left to chose from), and order matters, as it does with the digits.

Comment: @tienlee: Careful: Were the numbers in that case required to be positive, or merely non-negative?  (In other words, could $x_1 = 0$?)

Comment: But, my question was $x1+x2+x3+x4=35$ and I am getting the answer as $(38,35)$

Comment: @tienlee: Suppose you needed to answer $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 5$ with *positive* integers.  Should the answer be $C(7, 5)$ or $C(4, 2)$?  Enumerate the solutions—how many are there?

Comment: The solution to $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 31$ (with non-negative $y_i$) *is* a solution to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 35$ (with positive $x_i$) when you take $x_i = y_i+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for a)

Write
$$35=1+1+\dots+1$$
Now, in how many ways can you place three commas?
For instance $1,1+1,1+1+1,1+\dots+1$.

For b), you are not considering that the digits come after the letters.

Comment: The OP has taken into account the positions of the letters and numbers.  The OP's mistake is that the letter A has already been used, so there are only $25$ letters from which to choose the remaining letters.